# How can I exit powerfactory using Python in Unattended mode?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4

I am new to Python scripting and I am currently trying to get acquainted with python scripting and DigSILENT Powerfactory.

I have managed thus far to execute powerfactory, activate projects and execute a load flow but after my code ends, when I try to rerun it, it wont run. In order for it to run I need to close Spyder and reopen it. I believe this is related to the fact that powerfactory is still running in the background so I was wondering if there is any command that "forces" powerfactory to shut down after the code execution.

Any tip would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But faster than shutdown/reopen spyder is to restart the kernel with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: The problem is you lose every simulated value

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

app.PostCommand("exit")

Comment: There is somehow the problem that the program is not completely closed and can't be reopened until kernel or spyder is restarted